# Rating Bar returns the default Value

Tags: java, android, ratingbar

I have a problem with my application. After the user hits the "finish button" an "AlertDialog" comes up and the user has the ability to rate something.

My problem is when the user hits the ok button from the AlertDialog (positveButton) the rating bar returns the default value (0.0). I tried to use the OnRatingBarChangeListener and saved the rating in a variable but this didn't work either.

---

*Java Code:*

```
public RatingBar ratingBar;
```

AlertDialog

```js
AlertDialog.Builder build = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            final View view = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_rating, null); // This a have from another Stackoverflow question

build.setView(R.layout.dialog_rating);
ratingBar = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_ratingBar);
build.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
  @Override
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dia, int which) {
    Log.i("[Rate]", String.valueOf(ratingBar.getRating())); //This returns 0.0
    Log.i("[Rate]", "" + ratingBar); // Is Valid check
  }
});
AlertDialog dialog = build.create();
dialog.setTitle(R.string.rating_dialog_title);
ialog.show();
```

*XML Code*

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RatingBar
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.RatingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dialog_ratingBar"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="0.5"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try this Link: [How to get Rating from Ratingbar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7332660/6541084)

Comment: Nope, the problem is still there but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it.
For those who have the same problem:
I changed `final View view = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_rating, null);` to `final View view = this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_rating, null);`

Now it works fine

Comment: Getting the save value.  Can you help me?