# Getting 0.0 value from ratingBar.getRating(); (Default Value) even though I change the rating bar value?

Tags: android, ratingbar

I have looked  into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38975895/rating-bar-returns-the-default-value) but doesn't seem to work for me. I am displaying ratingbar in alert dialog. I get value only **0.0** on button pressed.  Below is the code:

**rateme.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RatingBar
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:numStars="5"
android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
android:stepSize="1.0"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Java.Code

```
 //Typecase
 final View view = this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.rateme, null);
 ratingBar=(RatingBar)view.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);

 AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = null;
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alertDialog.setTitle("Rate and Review");
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        alertDialog.setView(R.layout.rateme);
    }else{
        alertDialog.setMessage("Please  Rate and Review");
    }
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("SUBMIT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        final String myPackage = getPackageName();
                        String value=" "+ratingBar.getRating();
                        Log.d(TAG," "+value);   **//Getting value 0.0 although I change  ratingbar and submit.**
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("QUIT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                }).setCancelable(true).setIcon(android.R.drawable.star_big_on).create();
    ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
           //The toast below is not executed even when I chaned the ratingbar stars.
            Toast.makeText(Front.this, "Blank", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Log.d(TAG,"Reached on Listener");
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
 }
```

It seems that I have done everything correctly but I am getting value 0.0 (constant). What might have I mistaken?

Comment: where are you changing the value?

Comment: @Blackbelt This will popup a Rating Bar and change value when we slide on stars. Isn't that right?  Here's example https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-rating-bar-example/

Answer (score 0):

the problem lies here

```
   if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
       alertDialog.setView(R.layout.rateme);
   } else {
       alertDialog.setMessage("Please  Rate and Review");
   }
```

You don't need this if/else, since `setView` was part of Android since Api version 1. On the other end, your rating baris not the same you see in the dialog, since   `alertDialog.setView(R.layout.rateme);` inflates the rating bar again. Using `alertDialog.setView(view);`  should fix your issue

Comment: Are you sure? According to the documention setView was  added in API 21. but this doesn't make any sense I think coz I am running on Marshmallow. RatingBar view is fine. Problem is only I am getting 0.0 floating value event after I change rating bar.

Comment: pretty sure. Read it [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setView(android.view.View))

Answer (score 0):

#### What's wrong

You inflate the layout once, keep a reference to a RatingBar and then forget the layout.

```
final View view = this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.rateme, null);
ratingBar = (RatingBar)view.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
// You never work with view again.
```

Then AlertDialog.Builder inflates a different layout (based on the same resource id) which is actually shown.

```
alertDialog.setView(R.layout.rateme);
```

#### How to fix it

Use the layout you inflated.

```
final View view = this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.rateme, null);
ratingBar = (RatingBar)view.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
alertDialog.setView(view);
```

#### How to fix it even further

Use the dialog context (not activity context) so your dialog draws correctly when you have dark activity and want light dialogs.

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(alertDialog.getContext());
final View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.rateme, null);
ratingBar = (RatingBar)view.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
alertDialog.setView(view);
```

Always use the closest, most logical Context you can get when inflating views.